# Modify Javascript Variable with URL

Tags: javascript, html, variables, url, browser

Is it possible to change a javascript variable through the URL?

Here's an example of the code I'm trying to modify from a website. (`www.example.com`)

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var x = 0;

</script>
```

I want to change the variable `x` from `0` to `1`.

I want to do this by appending something to the URL. I'm not sure about the syntax, but I think it may be something like this:

```
www.example.com#javascript: var=1;
```

**Is it possible to change variable `x` by only modifying the URL?**

**EDIT:**
The duplicate question doesn't tell me how (if it's possible) to change the variable through the URL. Please let me know if that's not the case.

**Related Question:**
https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/134240/modify-javascript-variable-with-url-exploit

Comment: JavaScript on the page can look at [`window.location`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location) to decide what to do based on the URL. This requires the relevant JavaScript to already be present on the page.

Comment: That would be a serious security flaw, so browsers would not allow such a thing. If you control the JavaScript, you could (carefully) read part if the URL into a variable.

Comment: Please explain the reason for the downvotes. If you think it's a silly question, please just answer it. If it violates a site rule, please let me know. Thanks.

Comment: Please show an example URL from which you would like to retrieve/modify a variable, and show what the variable should become; without specifics this is a theoretical exercise and we're unable to offer any specific advice without guessing (which is of little use to you, and is too broad as a question). Incidentally I don't necessarily agree with the current close-reason, but unless you add some specifics the question is likely to remain closed, because we can't see that this question is not a duplicate. Or what this question is specifically asking.

Comment: Your questions shows a lack of research and is unclear. That's probably the reason for your down votes.

Comment: Sorry about that! I'll get to work clarifying it :)

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara Let me know if it's still unclear. Thanks.

Comment: As I said before, no, directly injecting scripts by URL should not be possible without an XSS vulnerably.

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara Ok, if you make that an answer, I can accept it :)

Comment: This question is closed, but I answered your other one on InfoSec. You might want to add the updated information from here though to make it a better question.

Comment: actually the question marked as duplicate seems to be exactly what you need.

Answer (score 0):

you can use:

```
 if(window.location.href.indexOf("your_link_to_check") > -1) {
      var x = 1;
    }
```

Comment: Would it be possible to run this from the address bar in a browser? I'm pretty new to this area of programming. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: no, you can use Chrome's console to test it

Comment: What exactly would I put under "your_link_to_check"? Could you please clarify on that point?